# How can I change the aqua theme in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, ui, themes, cocoa

How can I change the aqua theme/skin to a dark one in Yosemite? I'm referring to the window title bars, scroll bars, buttons, etc (the cocoa aqua ui theme?). Everything is grayish by default, but i'd like a dark theme.

Comment: I don't believe currently that there's a way to get a system wide dark mode for Yosemite, as the dark mode theme only effects the menu bar and dock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're still looking for a method to darken your UI in Yosemite, download Flavours 2 and choose the "Smooth Criminal" flavour.
[image: Here's a quick screenshot of "Smooth Criminal."]

Flavours 2 is still in Beta, but most things look great with this skin.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Finder icons with [LiteIcon](http://www.freemacsoft.net/liteicon/), freeware.

More icons than you could ever need at [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/?qh=&section=&global=1&q=mac%20icons)

[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) (freeware) can do custom [theming](http://support.alfredapp.com/appearance), but might require the [Powerpack](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/) (not free) for what you require.

There's also [ThemePark](https://web.archive.org/web/20180615013312/http://www.geekspiff.com:80/software/themepark/)

Comment: Thanks! Does Themepark work in Yosemite? The site seems to be "temporarily unavailable".

Comment: idk, sorry - I tried to check, but discovered the same thing. I guess we'll have to wait for it to come back up.

Comment: Hopefully it does!

Comment: I'm not sure why changing the appearance of Alfred is being mentioned here. It's not capable of theming the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences → General → Right under Appearance check "Use dark menu bar and dock"

Comment: I knew that already, and have that enabled. I was referring to the window title bars, scroll bars, buttons, etc (the cocoa aqua theme?). They are gray by default, but i'd like a dark theme.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question then.